# Google Spreadsheets add-on HTML sidebar URL address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm using a contact form in Spreadsheets add-on's HTML sidebar. 
Also I have a source confirmation, before I start receiving the messages:

```
Congrats, you're one step away from receiving forms on 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel 

Click the link below to confirm your form. 
To prevent spamming, you'll have to repeat this step for every page where you insert your form.
```

I noticed that confirmation was requested few times already and the only difference is one number:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-2lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel
```

The question is - will I keep getting new confirmation request emails and how many possible URL variations it may have or will it keep adding numbers to infinity and I will have to confirm them all?

I suppose that xxxxxxxxx part is my project ID or something related to my add-on, but what are those 0lu, 1lu, 2lu
They also appeared in a wrong order:
First -0lu-
Second -2lu-
Third -1lu-

Thanks for any clarification on that question.

Comment: Do you have 3 email addresses?

Comment: @I'-'I Nope, all forms have just 1 email address. But addon users are from different countries.